# Threading work results unexpected longer execution time

Tags: python, multithreading, io

I am trying to speed up the writing time on disk using multithreading. To see the effectiveness, I wrote the following code the measure the time between the two methods:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import random, time
import numpy as np
import threading


def file_write(filepath, V):
    filepath = open(filepath, 'w')
    np.savetxt(filepath, V, fmt='%i')
    filepath.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    filepath = 'output.txt'
    V = 10000
    dim = 128

    print('Starting generating ...')
    V_ = [random.randint(0, 2 ** dim) for _ in range(V)]
    V = list(set(V_))
    V = [('{0:0' + str(dim) + 'b}').format(x) for x in V]
    V = np.asarray([list(map(int, list(x))) for x in V], dtype=np.uint8)

    # This is Non-Threading write
    t0 = time.time()
    file_write(filepath, V)
    t1 = time.time()
    print('\n\n>> No-Thread Writing Time= %.2f '% (t1-t0))

    # Generating 10 threads
    thread_list = []
    for i in range(1, 10):
        t = threading.Thread(target=file_write, args=(filepath, V))
        thread_list.append(t)

    # Starts threads
    t0 = time.time()
    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.start()

    # Closing threads
    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.join()

    t1 = time.time()
    print('\n\n>> 10-Threads Writing Time= %.2f ' % (t1 - t0))
```

The results were surprising as below. The threading takes longer time than the non-threading work. Isn't supposed to be the opposite? I thought threading is faster!

```
Starting generating ...
>> No-Thread Writing Time= 0.26 
>> 10-Threads Writing Time= 2.44
```

Comment: *This is (probably) not a software problem.* Writing to a SATA disk is a sequential process. This means that you can only write one bit at a time. Writing from multiple threads won't help you. You should instead look at solving this problem through hardware. I would recommend looking at setting up a RAID array. NVMe PCIe on the other hand has multiple IO channels. Either way, speeding up write speeds should be solved through better hardware config, not OS threading.

Comment: Your threads are each trying to just do what your non-thread part does. And your threads are trying to write to  the same file, my guess thread 1 is writing and the rest of the threads have to wait for it to finish, then thread 2, etc

Comment: Thank you guys. I just realized that Writing on disk in most cases is a sequential process. This fact has been absent to me.